# Negate the output of the regex pattern

Tags: regex, negate

I want to negate the outcome of the regex pattern, so that it should return everything except the regex outcome.

Sample String:

```
SMTP:test.abc@xyz.com;smtp:test.123@xyz.biz;sip:test.123@xyz.biz
```

I have written a below regex which gives output as- test.abc@xyz.com

```
(?<=SMTP:)(.*?)(?=;)
```

Now i want everything except the above outcome i.e

```
SMTP:;smtp:test.abc@xyz.biz;sip:test.abc@xyz.biz
```

I am trying to negate but it is not working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What regex tool or language are you using here?

Comment: Simply replace with an empty string

Comment: Ok, so let me explain more on this. I have to pass it on as json request which has predfined API with two required values-
regex-"<pattern to find>"
replace-"<String with which pattern will be replace">

Basically, i want to return the final string as "test.abc@xyz.com" so i am working in reverse, like finding this pattern and then negating it so that i can get the rest and then i will replace that with "". So at the end i will have "test.abc@xyz.com". In other words, i have to write the regex for "SMTP:;smtp:test.abc@xyz.biz;sip:test.abc@xyz.biz"

Comment: Just matching [`^SMTP:|;.+`](https://regex101.com/r/zIgkXe/1) won't suffice, would it?

Comment: It would, but it will fail if the position of the "SMTP" changes..right?
smtp:test.abc@xyz.biz;SMTP:test.abc@xyz.com;sip:test.abc@xyz.biz

Comment: @user2223987 yes, it would fail if the data is not following the pattern...

Comment: Can't you just search for eg `.*?\bSMTP:(.*?);.*` and replace with captured `$1` like someone else already mentioned? See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aixJoz/1).

Comment: As per your selected answer, here another idea: [`SMTP:|(?:;|^)(?:(?!SMTP).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/OzKoq9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be overcomplicated, but if you need multiline matching and a smtp account can be in the beginning of a line, this:

```
(SMTP:)|(;[^(SMTP)]*)|(^[^(SMTP)]*)
```

would match:

- `SMTP:`
- anything after a `;` up until another `SMTP`
- anything at the beginning of a line (no need of ;) up until another `SMTP`

Have a look at [some tests here.](http://regexr.com/6e5cf)

This can break down if an email name contains `SMTP` in it, but I hope you won t have any.

Another approach is use your matching regex, `(?<=\SMTP:)(.*?)(?=\;)`, and keep deleting what it matches from the string.

Comment: Just to mention that `[^(SMTP)]` [represents a character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) class. It matches any character, that is not in the list. In this case any character besides `^`,`(`,`S`,`M`,`T`,`P`,`)` which is probably not desired. Perhaps you were thinking of something like `(?:(?!SMTP).)`.